# xUnit test Uwp project get 'Unsupported MRT profile type' exception

Tags: uwp, xunit

I am trying to test a UWP project with xUnit.
On create instance of *Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader()*, I get exception:
**Unsupported MRT profile type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073B20)**
Example method to test:

```
public int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
    return a + b;
}
```

With MsTest test is passed.

Comment: This looks like it is possibly an issue with UWP interaction: https://github.com/CodeConnect/AliveFeedback/issues/80

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?